# Most efficient way to write AutoMapper code?

Tags: c#, automapper

I recently gave Automapper a shot, and once I got it working it's absolutely fantastic. The issue is that the actual code that I have to write to setup the Automapper is kind of gross, and I'm wondering if the way I'm doing it can be improved upon or simplified. I'm using it (in the following example) to convert from my entity to a viewmodel. The field names are entirely different, so I have to manually create the mapping (AFAIK)

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<customer_master, CustomerViewModel>()
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.FirstName, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_firstname))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.LastName, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_lastname))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Id, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_id))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Address1, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_address1))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Address2, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_address2))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.City, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_city))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.State, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_state))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Zip, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_zip))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Country, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_country))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Email, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_email))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Phone, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_phone))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Fax, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_fax))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Active, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_active))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.Company, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.cm_company));

            cfg.CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, customer_master>()
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_firstname, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.FirstName))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_lastname, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.LastName))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_id, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Id))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_address1, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Address1))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_address2, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Address2))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_city, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.City))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_state, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.State))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_zip, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Zip))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_country, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Country))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_email, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Email))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_phone, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Phone))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_fax, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Fax))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_active, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Active))
            .ForMember
                (dst => dst.cm_company, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.Company));

        });
    }
}
```

Then in `Global.asax`:

```
AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
```

Mostly my questions are:

1. Do the field names have to be explicitely mapped like this because the names are so different?
2. Is there a way to only write the first map and then use it for the second as well? Entity -> ViewModel is the same as ViewModel -> Entity, it seems redundant to write these twice. I guess I'm looking for some sort of bidirectional option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all your conversions follow the same pattern: member X maps to member cm_X. If that is the case, you can simplify your code to this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {      
     // will remove "cm_" from destination when matching          
     // the fact you have different casing (Address vs cm_address)
     // is fine and is already handled
     cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes(new [] {"cm_"});
     // will remove "cm_" from source when mapping
     cfg.RecognizePrefixes(new[] { "cm_" });
     // will map in both directions
     cfg.CreateMap<Entity, Dto>().ReverseMap();                
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, my entity design doesn't **EXACLTY** follow this, the "cm_" changes based on the table name, and there may be underscores in the property name ("first_name" for instance), but this is a huge step in the right direction

Comment: That should be not a problem because you can add many prefixes (it is array of strings). Underscores can be handled too.

Answer (score 2):

If the field name is different you have to,  and for the bidirectional you can write only one mapping and at the end add :

```
.ReverseMap()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the field names have a definite pattern to them, like `cm_` in your example, you can look at defining conventions. See https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conventions. Maybe that will take care of the bulk of them?